# How would I initialize an empty relation and add elements to it in Rascal?

Tags: rascal

As simple as it seems, how do I initialize an empty relation (of type say, [str,int]), then add new elements to it? An approximate Rascal code:

```
rel[str,int] myReln={};

myReln.add(<"a",1>);
```

Samples for remove/modify operations would also be appreciated.

Comment: It looks as though you are assuming data is mutable, like in OO programming. This is not the case in Rascal. `myReln` points to the empty set `{}` which you can not change. What you _can_ do is make a new set and let `myReln' point to that, as Mark explains in his answer. Hope this helps! Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations are just a special form of sets, so all the operations available on sets are also available on relations. Your add operation would actually be

```
myReln += < "a", 1 >;
```

or

```
myReln = myReln + < "a", 1 >;
```

Removing items from a relation it similar to adding items to a relation. If you wanted to remove the tuple `< "a", 1>` from `myReln`, you would just write

```
myReln = myReln - < "a", 1 >;
```

or, as a shorthand

```
myReln -= < "a", 1 >;
```

If you don't know the entire tuple, but know you want to remove any tuple that starts with `"a"`, you have (at least) two choices. The easiest is to use the `domainX` function in the `Relation` library:

```
import Relation;
myReln = domainX(myReln, {"a"});
```

This will remove any tuples that have `"a"` as their first element. You could also have more than one item in this set, so if you want to remove any tuples starting with either `"a"` or `"b"` you could say:

```
myReln = domainX(myReln, {"a","b"});
```

The other option is to use pattern matching and comprehensions -- basically, to rebuild the relation by looking at each item in the relation and deciding if you should keep it. That would look like:

```
myReln = { <a,b> | <a,b> <- myReln, a != "a" };
```

Modification is then just some series of additions and deletions. Since the relations are immutable, we don't have a concept of in-place modification.

You can find documentation on Rascal sets here: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Set/Set.html. Special operations defined just for relations (again, sets of tuples) is here: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Relation/Relation.html

Comment: I'd prefer to use `myReln += {<"a",1">};` to avoid any ambiguity. Same with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to observe two principles:

- values are always immutable, i.e. once created they cannot be changed.
- to variables you can assign different values over time.

In your example:

- `rel[str,int] myReln={};`, fine variable `myRel` now has value `{}`.
- Adding a new value to a set or relation is done with the `+` operator. In your case, {} + <"a", 1>`.
- To assign this new value to `myRel`, you can write: `myRel = myReln + <"a", 1>`.
- A shorthand for this is `myReln += <"a", 1>`.

Deletion can be done using (in this example) set difference (`-`) or by decomposing the set value in parts using pattern matching and then constructing a new set.

Comment: Just to make the comment about immutability more concrete, this means that, if you assign `myReln = {}`, then assign `myReln2 = myReln`, changes to `myReln` will not be reflected in `myReln2`; adding a new tuple to a relation essentially creates a new relation, versus altering the existing relation in place.